# Does Swing keep scanning for keyboard input (java)?

Tags: java, swing, input, keyboard

I am trying to move an image that I have drawn onto a Jpanel using g.drawImage(). I need to know why this code isn't working (I am trying to reposition the image using the w key to move it up)

```
int CharX = 1;
int CharY = 30;

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent w) {
    CharY = CharY + 1;
    repaint();
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent w) {
    CharY = CharY + 1;
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: You can also change `CharY = CharY + 1;` to `CharY += 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're not actually checking for the w key just by naming the KeyEvent w. You need to check `if (w.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)`
2. Y-coordinates in Java start with 0 at the top, so you might want to subtract from `CharY` to make it go up.
3. This will update twice, once when the key is pressed, and again when you let it go. Not sure if that's what you actually want.
4. Without knowing what's inside your `paint` function, or if you even implemented it, it's hard to say if the problem isn't actually in there, but it should look something like

   `public void paint(Graphics g) {
       g.drawImage(yourImage, CharX, CharY, null);
   }`

Comment: where do I put repaint();?

Comment: While it is preferable to `implement Runnable` and put `repaint();` inside of the `run` function so that you can manage how often it happens, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work inside `keyPressed`. I've used it in `mouseMove` without any problems, so `keyPressed` should work, too.

Comment: The biggest problem with your code is that you don't have `implements KeyListener`. Once you add that, you'll need to make a constructor and put in it `addKeyListener(this);`. Then your `keyPressed` function should actually get called.

Comment: A constructor is a function that is called automatically when an object is created. It can be used to set up its initial state. Right now, your constructor should look like `public MyComponents() { addKeyListener(this); }`

Comment: I got an error when I put that and it suggested to put this addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);

Comment: and where abouts should I put the constructor?

Comment: Did you change `class MyComponents extends JComponent{` to `class MyComponents extends JComponent implements KeyListener {`? And the constructor goes anywhere inside the class with the rest of the functions. Doesn't really matter where it is relative to the other functions in the class already.

Comment: I don't think you need the `(KeyListener)` in `addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);` but other than that it looks like it should work. What happens when you run it?

Comment: when I press the w key nothing happens, Have I misplaced repaint();?

Comment: Yea, I just noticed that. Try putting `repaint();` back into the `keyPressed` function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31006/discussion-between-user1952565-and-jonhopkins)

Answer (score 0):

You should not call repaint() inside the keyPressed() or keyReleased() method.

```
public void keyPressed(w.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
    CharY = CharY + 1;
}
```

Call repaint() later.

Comment: @user1952565 See the comments on your post on why it doesn't do anything.

Comment: That's not going to compile, because w is unknown.